# Perl not playing video with vlc plugin

Tags: apache, perl, vlc

I am trying to play the video file with help of vlc-plugin.

Here is my code:-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;

my $file ='/home/abhishek/Videos/lua.mp4';
my $size = -s "$file";
my $begin=0;
my $end=$size;
(my $name, my $dir, my $ext) = fileparse($file, qr/\.[^.]*/);

open (my $fh, '<', $file)or die "can't open $file: $!";
binmode $fh;

print "Content-Type: application/x-vlc-plugin \n";
print "Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
print "Pragma: no-cache" ;
print "Accept-Ranges: bytes";
print "Content-Length:  $end - $begin\n\n";
print "Content-Range: bytes $begin'-'$end'/'$size";
print "Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$name$ext\"\n";
print "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary";
print "Connection: close"; 

my $cur=$begin;
seek($fh,$begin,0);
while(!eof($fh) && $cur < $end)
{
    my $buf=1024*16;
    read $fh, $buf, $end-$cur;
    $cur+=1024*16;
}
close $fh;
```

And here is my access log is writing

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Dec/2015:11:39:31 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/download.cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 484 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Dec/2015:11:39:32 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/download.cgi HTTP/1.1" 200 447 "-" "(null)"
```

As I checked what does this mean from [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/logs.html) site,here is what i got

`If no content was returned to the client, this value will be "-". To log "0" for no content, use %B instead.`

No content is returning to the client.It is returning null.
I am not able to figure out what is going wrong. Any help what will be grateful.

And please suggest me what should i do to play the video and I am not sure  is this the correct way to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I see numerous major problems with the headers you are printing:

```
print "Content-Type: application/x-vlc-plugin \n";
```

This MIME type is primarily used in an `<embed>` tag to invoke VLC. The correct MIME type for this file type is probably `video/mp4`.

```
print "Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
print "Pragma: no-cache" ;
```

These headers, and a number of the other ones following, are missing terminal newlines (`\n`). This will cause them to run together, causing unexpected results.

```
print "Accept-Ranges: bytes";
```

Along with not having a newline, this header is telling the browser that this resource supports range requests. Your script doesn't actually implement this, though, which will cause browsers to get very confused.

```
print "Content-Length:  $end - $begin\n\n";
```

Content-Length must be a single number representing the total length of the resource (e.g, `Content-Length: $size`). Also, you've got *two* newlines here, which will cause all the following headers to be treated as part of the content.

```
print "Content-Range: bytes $begin'-'$end'/'$size";
```

This header would normally be used with range requests, but you haven't fully implemented this feature, so this header will just confuse matters.

```
print "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary";
```

This header is meaningless here — it's primarily used in email. Leave it out.

```
print "Connection: close";
```

This header will be set as needed by the web server. CGI scripts shouldn't generate it.

You're also missing the double newline that needs to follow the last header.

Comment: These content print should be handled by a perl module with a sub to standardlize it, I remember I had a hardtime to make it working, now we still facing the same problem, there must be a module existing today

Answer (score 0):

I am too lazy to get it fully working, Here is a few suggestions
which does not fit into comments

Definitely will move you forward.

```
# format is in the detail
my $content_length = $end - $begin;
print "Content-Type: text/html\r\n";
print "Content-Type: application/x-vlc-plugin\r\n";
print "Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0\r\n";
print "Pragma: no-cache\r\n" ;
print "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n";
print "Content-Length: $content_length", "\r\n";
print "Content-Range: bytes ${begin}-${end}/${size}\r\n";
print "Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$name$ext\"\r\n";
print "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n";
print "Connection: close\r\n";
print "\r\n";
################################
#
# flush is needed
#
# ##############################
use IO::Handle;
STDOUT->autoflush;

my $cur=$begin;
seek($fh,$begin,0);
while(!eof($fh) && $cur < $end)
{
    my $buf=1024*16;
    read $fh, $buf, $end-$cur;
    $cur+=1024*16;
    ##############################
    #   I suspect you will need this
    #
    ###############################
    print $buf;
}
close $fh;
```